# Post File array using AngularJS and Jersey

Tags: angularjs, jersey, ng-file-upload

I am trying to post an array of files using ngFileUpload. ngFileUpload will transform the array into a FormData object using the following form:

```
inputName[$index] = [File Object]
```

Is there a way to use regex or ignore the [] in Jersey?

```
public String myResource(@FormDataParam("inputName") List<FormDataBodyPart> files) {
    // code
}
```

Or how can I remove the [] in angular before sending the request?

Comment: You can use `arrayKey` option in angular. See the module documentation full reference for more details: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for